# Print more than ANSI color values in Perl

Tags: perl, colors, ansi-escape

I love Perl's `Term::ANSIColor` module but is it possible to print out colours other than the ones provided?

I'm trying to print out words with a range between deep red and bright green, with a decent number of steps between them. Is there a way to supply an RGB value or something to change the color of the text?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use [Term::ExtendedColor](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-ExtendedColor/).
You can use 256 colors by this module.

Comment: Is worth noting that the colors displayed are dependend on the terminal the OP is useing.

Answer (score 1):

A few terminals even accept full 8-bit RGB colour specifications.

```
$ perl -E 'say "\e[38:2:255:100:80mHello\e[m"'
Hello
```

This may be printed in `rgb(255,100,80)` colour pink. Depends on your terminal.

As a way to obtain xterm256 colour values out of arbitrary RGB combinations, you might also like `Convert::Color`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Convert::Color;
use Convert::Color::XTerm;

foreach my $hue ( map { $_ * 15 } 0 .. 120/15 ) {
   my $c = Convert::Color->new( "hsv:$hue,1,1" );
   my $index = $c->as_xterm->index;
   print "\e[38:5:${index}mHue=$hue\e[m\n";
}
```

I'd paste the output here but it's hard to convey the colours in a comment :)